# Editor toolbar bug

Tags: bug, editor

I'm facing a bug since about a month I think. The editor toolbar on the desktop site seems to be created multiple time and forever:

[image: Bug on electronics.stackexchange]

[image: Bug on Stack Overflow]

This happens in all the sites. I tested on Chrome 53, Firefox 47 and Edge 38 and happens on all of them. I posting this from the Android app because the desktop site is unusable for me.

Console log:

[image]

---

This is the network and console while openning [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670030/how-to-swipe-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-in-android%20%22%22) question:

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce this and getting nowhere. Does it happen immediately when you open the page? Does it happen on any other computers? Are you behind a proxy? Are there any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Check your machine for malware/viruses. Turn off your anti virus and/or any security software, just for sake of testing this. (Those have habit of injecting stuff to pages)

Comment: Also, just as a workaround, try browsing in https, e.g. `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` it might block whatever is injecting those things to the page.

Comment: This also happens on my Android phone on Chrome with desktop mode. I can reproduce it easily while I'm on my home WiFi network but it's much harder to make it happen when connected to mobile data. It happens right after I open the page and the editor is loaded. I scanned my PC and found no malware or viruses, also I tried on Chrome incognito to discard an extension problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard browsing with HTTPS makes everything work perfectly again! Maybe something related to my network or ISP provider? I'm gonna try on another WiFi network

Comment: When were these screenshots taken? And on which sites?

Comment: @AdamLear They were taken today, at the same time I created the question. The console log is on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Andres we sent you an email to help us diagnose this.  Can you also post your "Network" tab in chrome?

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas I edited the question with the requested Information. Yes, I just replied to the email :)

Comment: Well, until this is fixed, just browse the secured site. I still suspect some local software you have which mess up with network traffic, but might as well be in the ISP level.

Comment: @Andres we have pushed a fix for this - can you check to see if it is still an issue?

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas, yes, still happening for me :/ Do you need new screenshots from the network and console tabs?

Comment: @andres nope, we will keep looking at this